# Is it possible to generate gcov .info files from html files generated using genhtml

Tags: gcov, lcov

I have html report for code coverage.Is it possible to convert this report back to info file format?

Comment: Since the HTML report is generated from coverage data files. It makes no sense to convert HTML report back to info file format (assuming info capture format of lcov). Why don't you just use the generated info file using lcov?

Comment: The generated info files are lost due to device cleanup.We have reports on different server so wanted to know if there is way to convert it back

Comment: You can write the code for it but it would not be very useful. What you could is capture and zip the generated .info file along with the generated HTML report on the server.